# How can I get a string containing a defined number of spaces?

Tags: c#, .net

In another language, I've used the function `SPACE(10)`, to give me a string of 10 spaces. I want to convert this to C#.NET.

I have used `string.Empty().PadLeft(10)`.

Is this correct?

Comment: What does exactly `SPACE()` do ?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/k6ethaxs(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: For the record, you don't have "a code", you have "code" :)

Comment: What was wrong with `String space10 = "".PadLeft(10)`? http://ideone.com/Z3uz9q Apart from that, your question is unclear since you're asking us about your `SPACE`-method which you haven't shown.

Answer (score 7):

Simply use:

```
new String(' ', 10);
```

Here's the MSDN documentation:

> [`String` Constructor (`Char`, `Int32`)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/xsa4321w.aspx)
>
> Initializes a new instance of the `String` class to the value indicated by a specified Unicode character repeated a specified number of times.

Answer (score 4):

There is an [overload of the `string` constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xsa4321w.aspx) for this:

```
var spaces = new string(' ', 10);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`String Constructor (Char, Int32)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xsa4321w.aspx)

> Initializes a new instance of the String class to the value indicated
>   by a specified Unicode character **repeated a specified number of times**.

```
string s = new string(' ', 10);
```